# Display Class member value using ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator

I am new to java and android. I have created a class with definition below :

```
public class MyClass {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

Now I am creating objects of class, initializing value to class members and adding objects to array list like this :

```
MyClass myclassobj1 = new MyClass();
myclassobj1.id = 1;
myclassobj1.name = "Abhishek";
MyClass myclassobj2 = new MyClass();
myclassobj2.id = 2;
myclassobj2.name = "Kumar";


ArrayList<MyClass> taskList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
taskList.add(myclassobj1);
taskList.add(myclassobj2);
```

Now I assign arraylist to iterator like this

```
Iterator it = taskList.iterator();
```

Now when I iterate over array list I want to Log the values I added to class members, which I am not able to do

```
while (it.hasNext())
            Log.d(TAG,it.next().getClass().getDeclaredFields().toString());
```

Please help

Comment: "I want to Log the values I added to class members, which I am not able to do", what do you mean by this?

Comment: my first line is, i am new to java, and then there is a negative point. Is it not the place to take help when I am a novice ?

Comment: For the record, I did not downvote you. That said, knowing how to ask questions has got nothing to do with being a novice in a particular technology.

Comment: I don't agree,  when you are a novice you have different types of doubts and you ask questions accordingly. Please recall your days. And when you get expert those doubts become wrong way of asking.

Comment: The fundamental problem with your question is that you don't show what is the expected output and what is the actual output that you get. That's the crux of asking good questions here at SO. Like I said, asking good questions has got nothing to do with how much you know about the subject. You wanted to know why you got negative points.. this is the reason for it.

Comment: the person who was able to understand the requirement did answer

Comment: Lucky for you. That's not always going to be the case (which is apparent from your question history)

Comment: And thats the reason he has very good reputation

Comment: Please read my first line. "I am new to java and android"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do something like this instead:

```
List<MyClass> taskList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
taskList.add(new MyClass(1, "kumar1"));
taskList.add(new MyClass(2, "kumar2"));
```

the in the class MyClass define the constructor with parameters...

**AND** override the toString Method in the class so you can see something human-readable when you print the object...

having done this, you will see how this will work:

```
for (MyClass mx: taskList) {
    Log.d(TAG, mx.toString());
}
```

an example of how the MyClass can look like this:

```
class MyClass {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public MyClass(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "MyClass [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
```

## Edit:

I suspect you want the iterator to get the values hold in the List and not the name of the field...

the implementation looks like:

```
Iterator<MyClass> it = taskList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next().getClass().getDeclaredFields().toString());
    System.out.println(it.next().getId());
    System.out.println(it.next().getName());
}
```

you will need for sure the respective getters...

```
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to get the values when I am using the iterator?

Comment: so in the class I need to define methods to return id and name member values. Right?

Comment: it.next().getId() gives error the getters are not accessible

Comment: Thank you so much man, you were very very helpful. Even though you approach is very much correct as per Java coding, in my code the only thing i was not able to do correctly was  Iterator<MyClass> it = taskList.iterator(); and i did it like  Iterator it = taskList.iterator(); And this was able to pick up from your code.

Answer (score 0):

If every other things seem fine then, you can iterate over the arraylist as:

```
for (MyClass task : taskList) {
    Log.d(TAG, task.id + " " + task.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These parts were basically missing in my code and thats why I was not able to get (Log) the values of class member

first :

```
public class MyClass {

     int id;
     String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id+"";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Second :

```
Iterator<MyClass> it = taskList.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()){
            MyClass myobj = it.next();
            Log.d(TAG,myobj.getId());
            Log.d(TAG,myobj.getName());
        }
```